# Why the pipe() in my C code keeps returning -1

Tags: c, pipe

I have what I believe should be a rather simple question but for whatever reason, I can't seem to understand. In the code I'm trying to write my intention is to create a child process that sends a pointer to the parent process. The pointer being a struct that I defined myself. The parent process then prints out one of the fields.

I've used gdb to determine that it the return of the pipe(pipe_id); call is -1 - the reason for my code exiting. I'm not sure why this keeps happening. Any thoughts?

```
/*
    -- Includes
*/
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
    -- Definitions
*/
#define BUF_SIZE  100
#define COMMAND_MESSAGE 1
#define MESSAGE_SIZE (sizeof(int)) * (20 * sizeof(char))


struct Msg {
   int message_type;
   char message[20];
};


int main() {
    /*
    * Local vars
    */

    /* Declare a handle for a pipe */
    int pid;
    /* Declare a handle to reference pipe ID */
    int pipe_id[2];
    /* Declare a return value for pipe init */  
    int ret;
    /* Define a buffer to store information */
    char buff[BUF_SIZE];    
    /*
    * Computation
    */
    /* Init the pipe */
    ret = pipe(pipe_id);
    if(ret = -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }
    /* Create a new process -- this will simulate transmission to test
        out the INGEST code.. 
    */
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* 
            Description:
            Create a child process to simulate sending data to the parent.
        */
        printf("Simulator execute.\n");
        /* Declare a MsgId */
        struct Msg m;
        /* Define attributes for message */
        m.message_type = COMMAND_MESSAGE;
        int count = 0;
        strcpy(m.message,"Extract from Pool");
        /* Write to one end of the pipe */
        write(pipe_id[1],&m, MESSAGE_SIZE);
        /* Exit when necessary */
        while(true) {
            if(count = 1000000) {
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    else {

        /* 
            Description:
            The parent process handles messages that it receives from 
            the child.
        */

        /* Define a handle for a received message */
        printf("Receiver execute.\n");
        struct Msg *received_m;
        /* Define the exit flag */
        read(pipe_id[0],received_m,MESSAGE_SIZE);
        printf("%d\n",received_m->message_type);
        exit(0);
    }   

}
```

Comment: `if(ret = -1) {` ?

Comment: Aside from the issue John3136 is alluding to (confusing `=` and `==`), the parent and child processes occupy different address spaces.  So passing a pointer from one to the other is not going to do anything useful.  Instead, you could use shared memory or something similar to pass the information between processes.

Comment: As what @JimLewis already pointed out, a child is a complete clone of the parent. What you thought is shared between them is really a complete clone. The pointers may even point to the same address but in reality those addresses are relative to the address space of each process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if(ret = -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

You need `if(ret == -1)` because `if (ret = -1)`is considered as always true. More precisely :

> An assignment evaluates to the value that is assigned, and any non-zero value evaluates to "true" in a boolean context

Comment: Nice work spotting the error, but please be accurate in your answer: an assignment evaluates to the value that is assigned, and any non-zero value evaluates to "true" in a boolean context ....

Comment: Like what @FelixPalmen said, be accurate in your answer. With your current answer, it makes it sound that `if (ret = 0)` will always return true. Nice spotting the issue nonetheless.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Edited my answer with your beautifully said explanation. Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt reply. I feel silly for not seeing that earlier. My code is working fine now!